# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript code not working - why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

I have used code like this in the past to successfully pop up an alert message on my asp.net webpage. Now it is not working. I can't figure out why.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, 
     "alert('This pops up')", true);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "12344",
     "alert('This pops up')", true); and it worked perfectly fine for me. Check the Source of page to see if its emitting the code and if that is fine.

Comment: It's because registering a script with ScriptManager is only registering. You need something to fire it off, like a button onclick event

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- Use `GetType()` instead of `typeof(Page)` in order to bind the script to your actual page class instead of the base class,
- Pass a key constant instead of `Page.UniqueID`, which is not that meaningful since it's supposed to be used by named controls,
- End your Javascript statement with a semicolon,
- Register the script during the `PreRender` phase:

---

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourUniqueScriptKey", 
        "alert('This pops up');", true);
}
```

Comment: No, I can't work. You MUST use ID of current UpdatePanel instead "this"

Comment: @vNext, what do you mean? The first argument to [RegisterStartupScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) is a `Control` or a `Page`, depending on the overload used, never a string.

Answer (score 26):

Try this code...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Hi');", true);
```

Where `UpdatePanel1` is the `id` for `Updatepanel` on your page

Comment: If you have a Repeater inside of an Ajax UpdatePanel and you try to register a javascript from the Repeater's OnItemCommand you must do it this way.  This should definitely be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the updatepanel id in the first argument if the control causing the script is inside the updatepanel else use the keyword 'this' instead of update panel here is the code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel3, this.GetType(), UpdatePanel3.UniqueID, "showError();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue. However this issue was caused because of the way i designed the pages to bring the requests in. I placed all of my .js files as the last thing to be applied to the page, therefore they are at the end of my document. The .js files have all my functions include. The script manager seems that to be able to call this function it needs the js file already present with the function being called at the time of load. Hope this helps anyone else.