# How we can call javascript function from code-behind in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have this javascript function :

```
function showLoader() {
           document.getElementById("loaderState").style.display = 'inline';
       }
```

And I have a button :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="btnSignUp_Click" />
```

I am tryong to call that js function in code behind :

```
protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int i = users.AddNewUser();
        if (i != 0)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                GetType(),
                "btnSignUp",
                "showLoader();",
                true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
}
```

But not worked!!! Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to comment everything in `btnSignUp_Click`, then add just this line: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "btnSignUp", "showLoader();", true);` ? Maybe it's because the `i` value is 0

Comment: No, i am sure that i is not 0

Comment: I tested all code but `if(i != 0)` and it work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute javascript function after asp.net postback without Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320999/execute-javascript-function-after-asp-net-postback-without-ajax)

Comment: i was used update panel. if use onclientclick="showLoader()" it work fine, but if call it from code behind it does not work.

Comment: @farzaneh_t: first: you don't explain about `UpdatePanel`.
second: i tested your codes without `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Sorry, I realized why my code does not work. I had used Response.Redirect after calling the JavaScript function.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
 this,
 GetType(), 
"btnSignUp",
"showLoader();",
 true);
```

See these similar question:

[ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript code not working - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994040/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-code-not-working-why)

[ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484978/clientscript-registerstartupscript-not-working)

[ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(...) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091684/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int i = users.AddNewUser();
        if (i != 0)
        {
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "btnSignUp", "showLoader()", true);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
}
```