# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock from UserControl Of MasterPage

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

I have master page. In master page I have one UserControl. In this UserControl I have one button . When I complete everything with this button event I want to call Javascript function from page. Below is my code :

**Button Event**

```
    protected void btnAddCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something Here

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alertmessage();", true);
    }
```

**Javascript Function On same UserControl**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function alertmessage() {
       alert("Call Successfull");
   }
 </script>
```

But this javascript function never been called. When same UserControl is inside page it works. but if it is inside masterpage it doesn't.

Comment: The above code is working. Please post the mark up of Master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code works. Make sure if you have user ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScrip anywhere other part of the page then you have terminate Javascript code with **;**. 
If inline javascript fails, no other function is called.

Refer: [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript code not working - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994040/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-code-not-working-why)

Comment: `RegisterStartupScript` did not work for me, but have changed it to `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and it worked, BUT only after changing `this` to `this.Page` (which is the subpage), The Master page itself doesn't store any scripts, it renders it to the sub page this you have to register it to the sub page. Example: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "myscr", "alert('test');", true);`

Comment: Many Thanks @Pierre. Post it as answer. It would be help for other developers too.