# asp.net and html5 web storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am doing an application and I believe html5 web storage, particularly localstorage, will be of great help to me. And surprisingly it is not that easy as I thought.  Maybe I don't really understand the whole concept as I am not skilled in JavaScript for that matter.

Now below is the code I am using to call the JavaScript function in an external .js file.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "StoreUserLogin", "StoreUserLogin('" + this.LoginHiddenField.Value + "');", true);
```

Below the above code is the JavaScript function:

```
function StoreUserLogin(emailAddress) {
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    //var emailAddress = document.getElementById('LoginHiddenField');

    window.sessionStorage.emailname = emailAddress;
    alert("Information from sessionStorage:- " + window.sessionStorage.emailname);
}
else
    alert("Browser does not support storage");
```

}

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: The problem is, it looks like it's not working and I don't know what is wrong. I want to make it work please.

Answer (score 0):

first you should follow mozilla recommendations and use `sessionStorage.setItem();` and `sessionStorage.getItem();`

But by the way you are not doing it the wrong way.

the first thing to know about `sessionStorage` it's not persistant , when the user will close it's browser all data inside will be wipe, not in case you use `localStorage`.

When you store something inside `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, javascript perform a `.toString()` opération on data you want to save.
So if you have to save a object, use `JSON.stringify()`  before saving on sessionStorage to stringify your object the good way, and only after save this string inside sessionStorage;

look at this page for more informations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Edit:  if it's not working in your if statement try to do this:

```
if (typeof (Storage) === "function")
```

Comment: @Bainn , is your c# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript registration working ? have  try to put a `console.log()`  or a `debugger`inside your javascript file to know if he is called ? 

if it's not look a this stackoverflow post on ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript , because it's where is the problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994040/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-code-not-working-why

Comment: Hmmm! The point now is, like you suspected, the script is not being run at all.  I have move the following code <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/testskills.js"></script>
 to the top section. But the same.  How can I get the script to run?

Comment: @Bainn when you register your RegisterStartupScript page already exist , you have to register this callback during the PreRender phase look at url linked inside my first comment , at the most voted answer