# Calling jQuery function from C# MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, call

How do I call Jquery function from C#? I have tried using registerStartupScript but I don't understand how it works still and it isn't working anyway. It doesn't enter jquery function at all

```
Page page = new Page();
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, this.GetType(), "script", "publishDialog();", true);
```

```js
function publishDialog() {
    $(".alert").dialog({
        modal: true,
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
    You must be signed in to upload music
</div>
```

**Edit:**
If the user clicks on publish button and no files are selected then I want to display the jquery ui dialog popup box that tells them to select a file. I need this line `uploadedSongs.Count(x => x.IsSelected) == 0` to check if they have not selected a file. Is their anyway I can get this into my jquery function then?

```
[HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Publish(IEnumerable<UploadedSong> uploadedSongs)
        {
            Page page = new Page();
            if (uploadedSongs.Count(x => x.IsSelected) == 0)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, this.GetType(), "script", "publishDialog();", true);
                return View("../Users/UserProfile", uploadedSongs);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("../Home/Index");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You seldom need to run client-side script from server-side. The two are completely separate beasts. What is the overall aim you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994040/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-code-not-working-why Methinks it has the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't try to register startup scripts like this. Instead you should set a value on your Model that is interpreted by your view logic. Something like this:

```
var myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
myViewModel.NeedsToRunJs = true; //some logic
return View(myViewModel);
```

Then in the Razor View:

```
@if(Model.NeedsToRunJs)
{
    <script>
        /* js to run */
    </script>
}
```

Or, if you want the javascript to be external, add the `src`:

```
@if(Model.NeedsToRunJs)
{
    <script src="someFile.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for another way if possible rather than putting script in views, rather have them in external js files

Comment: then do `<script src="someFile.js"><script>` instead

Comment: also, having view logic in the view is way better than having a javascript function in the controller.