# RegisterStartupScript not writing any script for firefox asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, firefox

This seems to be a weird scenario but the asp.net's `RegisterStartupScript` does not throw any scripts on the page for firefox.
This works fine for chrome.
The code is as below:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "testfunc", "<script type='text/javascript'>function testfunc(){ alert('hi123'); } testfunc(); </script>", false);
```

When I do "View page source" for chrome the code is seen but for firefox its nothing.
Also alert gets fired for chrome but, obviously, for firefox there is no alert.

I have also tried with the last parameter in the above mentioned code i.e. `addScriptTags` as true and removing the script tag from inside but to no avail.

The following is the screenshot for your reference.
The firefox version is 39.0 and that of chrome is 44.0.2, if this information matters.

[image]

Please let me know if any more information is required from my end.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to register javascript or AJAX script?.I see you are specifying script type=javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by moving the related code to the `prerender` event of the page.

So the code looks like the following

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "testfunc", "<script type='text/javascript'>function testfunc(){ alert('hi123'); } testfunc(); </script>", false);
}
```

I figured out the solution from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994040/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-code-not-working-why)

Hope this helps others!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To register javascript to the page use ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript .check the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx) for correct usage

use it like this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "testfunc", "<script type='text/javascript'>function testfunc(){ alert('hi123'); } testfunc(); </script>", false);
```

or like this

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alertscript","<script>alert('Hai');</script>");
```

Comment: I am getting compile error as "No  overload of method RegisterStartupScript takes 4 arguments". A similar error occurred for the second solution you have provided.

Comment: Hi Shreesha, I got it working finally. I moved the same code to preRender event and it worked! Thanks for your help!