# Execute javascript within aspx timer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer

I have a javascript with adds a searchbox over my gridview. It loads with the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<thead></thead>').prependTo('table#ctl00_MainContent_GVOPL').append($('table#ctl00_MainContent_GVOPL tr:first'));
    $('table#ctl00_MainContent_GVOPL tbody tr').quicksearch({
        reset: true,
        resetClass: "resetButton",
        resetLabel: "Zurücksetzen",
        position: 'before',
        attached: 'table#ctl00_MainContent_GVOPL',
        stripeRowClass: ['odd', 'even']
    });
    $(".qs_input").focus();
});
```

With a timer I update the gridview. After the first update the searchbox disappear. The idea is to add the javascript to execute also in the timer. But how can I do that?

Timer:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" />

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...build my gridview...
}
```

Comment: try like this:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994129/7036750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the binding of the searchbox again after a PostBack

Wrap your Javascript in a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bindSearchBox();
    });

    function bindSearchBox() {
        $('<thead></thead>').prependTo('table#ctl00_MainContent_GVOPL').append($('table#ctl00_MainContent_GVOPL tr:first'));
        .....
    }
</script>
```

And then call that function from code behind when reloading the GridView in a Timer Tick.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...build my gridview...
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "bindBox", "bindSearchBox()", true);
}
```