# Draw image into canvas using pngbase64 string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, canvas

i'm trying to draw an image inside canvas using base64 string also resize the canvas with img size but it doesn't working here is the code

```
**aspx code**



 <script src="../Scripts/MapGenerator/MapGeneraterScript.js"></script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenFieldMapBaseString" value="" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenFieldCanvasWidth" value="" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenFieldCanvasHeight" value="" runat="server" />
    <canvas id="canvasMasterPlan" style="border:solid;border-color:#353030;cursor:crosshair;" onclick="getImageCoords(event,this)">
    </canvas>

**code behind**

     System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgBytes));
    hiddenFieldCanvasHeight.Value = img.Height.ToString();
    hiddenFieldCanvasWidth.Value= img.Width.ToString();
    String base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
    hiddenFieldMapBaseString.Value= String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}\"", base64String);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "draw", "drawMap();", true);

**Javascript code**

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
strokestate = 0;
//Draw image into canvas
function drawMap() {
    c.width = document.getElementById("<%=hiddenFieldCanvasWidth.ClientID%>").value;
    c.height = document.getElementById("<%=hiddenFieldCanvasHeight.ClientID%>").value;
    var imageString = document.getElementById("<%=hiddenFieldMapBaseString.ClientID%>").value;
    c.drawImage(imageString, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: nothing it just show a blank canvas with default size

Comment: @Froopy nothing happened i get same results

Comment: is there any issue in invoking javascript funtion drawMap()

Comment: Where is drawMap being called?

Comment: in code behind section    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "draw", "drawMap();", true);

Comment: Did you register the script during the [pre-render phase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4994129/6871531)?

Comment: no i didn't register